# Swap function for heaps seems screwy

Tags: c

Yo. I have this extremely simple swap function that seems to not work. Probably a pointer issue so any advice would be nice.

```
void swap(pQueue *h, int index1, int index2) {
  student *temp = &h->heaparray[index1];
  h->heaparray[index1] = h->heaparray[index2];
  h->heaparray[index2] = *temp;    
}
```

`pQueue` is a heap pointer, `index1` and `index2` are guaranteed to be valid indices.

`student *temp` does get the value of `heaparray[index1]` but when `heaparray[index2]` is assigned the temp value, the `heaparray[index2]` stays the same. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to copy the actual value of `h->heaparray[index1]` (not its address) into `temp` and then later copy that value into `h->heaparray[index2]`, like so:

```
void swap(pQueue *h, int index1, int index2) {
  student temp = h->heaparray[index1];
  h->heaparray[index1] = h->heaparray[index2];
  h->heaparray[index2] = temp;    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`*temp` doesn't get the value of `heaparray[index1]`, it gets its address.

Comment: So how do I get the node to physically transfer?

Comment: Actually, `*temp` does get the value; it's `temp` that gets the address.

Comment: This is true.. I tested it and I can call all the values of the node. So why doesn't the temp assignment work?